# Cannot Wake up Atmel ATSHA204 Using I2C

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver, i2c, atsha204

I've recently been given the task of writing drivers for some of the I2C devices in our product. I was a complete beginner at this, but I've managed to use a mixture of `i2cset` and `i2cget` along with `smbus` to control some LEDs.

My latest task is to read a 7 byte serial number from the EEPROM of an [Atmel ATSHA204](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8740-CryptoAuth-ATSHA204-Datasheet.pdf) chip. My first job is to wake up the chip. The data sheet says this is done as follows

> The Wake condition requires either that the system processor manually drive 
>       the SDA pin low for tWLO, or that a data byte of 0x00 is transmitted at a 
>       clock rate sufficiently slow that SDA is low for a minimum period of tWLO.
>       When the device is awake, the normal processor I2C hardware and/or software
>       can be used for device communications up to and including the I/O sequence
>   required to put the device back into low-power (sleep) mode.

So it seems I have to manually set one of the I2C pins low for a time of tWLO which is apparently at least 60 microseconds before I can use conventional I2C calls. I'm really not sure how this is done, Ideally I'd do this in `C`, so would some variation of the following work?

```
int file;     
file = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);
if (file < 0)
{
    exit(1);
}

int addr = 0x64; // Address of LED driver

if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0)
{
    return 1;
}

write(file, 0x00, 1); // write a 0x00 to the chip to wake it up
```

I guess I'm not sure about the last bit, how do I keep writing until the device has woken up? I'd appreciate any help with this, as low-level programming such as this is new to me.

Comment: You might have better luck on electronics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to pass `0x00` to the `write` function.  That param isn't a value, it's a pointer to a buffer containing the data.  You need to know what clock speed your I2C is running.  That will determine how many bytes of 0x00 need to be written satisfy the required duration for wakeup.

Answer (score 0):

Below could help you to awake the chip

```
bool wakeup (int fd)
{
  unsigned char buf[4] = {0};
  bool awake = false;
  if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFD) < 0)
        perror ("Invalid FD.\n");
  while (!awake){
     if (write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 1){
        printf ("Device is awake!\n");
     }
     if (read (fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) == 4){
        printf ("Awake Done!\n");
        awake = true;
     }
     else {     
        printf ("Failed to awake the device!");
        break;
     }
    }
 return awake;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with that code: it's an infinite loop if nothing responding on the stream...